# Python, geometry and visualisation

Tags: python, geometry, visualization

I'm looking for a Python library that would allow me to visualise geometrical data. Nothing extremely complicated, just a bunch of points in the plane or space and a few basic shapes that I would generate.

I had a look at [this question and the answers to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076778/good-geometry-library-in-python), but the focus over there seems to be on computation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [Matplotlib/mplot3D](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/mplot3D)?