# Shapely intersection: parallel planes

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, intersection, shapely

I'm working on determining relationships (boundary/interior intersections) between two 3D objects (triangular faces) and stumbled on [Shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely), which I am interested in using instead of implementing my own point/segment/ray/triangle intersection functions.

However, I'm running into the following problem:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import Polygon
>>> poly = Polygon([(0,1,1),(1,-1,1),(-1,-1,1)])
>>> poly2 = Polygon([(0,1,0),(1,-1,0),(-1,-1,0)])
>>> poly.intersects(poly2)
True
>>> poly.equals(poly2)
True
```

The problem I seem to be running into is that the two polygons are equal in their 2D orthogonal projections (same triangle), but in different planes (one's at Z=1, other at Z=0), but Shapely is saying they're equal and intersect.

Is there some magic I'm missing to make shapely think in 3 dimensions?  I've been googling, but every example I've seen so far is only in two dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Shapely manual](http://toblerity.github.com/shapely/manual.html#geometric-objects), it states that the following for the z coordinate plane for geometric objects:

> *A third z coordinate value may be used when constructing instances, **but has no effect on geometric analysis. All operations are performed in the x-y plane.***

If your calculations require the z coordinate plane, then Shapely might not be for you. Of course, you could try to get the points of the polygon as a list and compare it to other polygons. However, if you want to have a Python geometric library that can handle the z dimension, you can find some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076778/good-geometry-library-in-python).