# Finding coordinate points of intersection with two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

This sort of question is a tad bit different the normal 'how to find the intersection of two lines' via numpy. Here is the situation, I am creating a program that looks at slope stability and I need to find where a circle intersects a line.

I have two numpy arrays:

One array gives me a normal (x, y) values of an elevation profile in 2D

The other array is calculated values of coordinates (x, y) that spans the circumference of a circle from a defined centre.

I need to somehow compare the two at what approximate point does the coordinates of the circle intersect the profile line?

Here some data to work with:

```
circ_coords = np.array([
                        [.71,.71],
                        [0.,1.]
                       ])

linear_profile = np.array([
                           [0.,0.],
                           [1.,1.]
                         ])
```

I need a function that would spit out say a single or multiple coordinate values saying that based on these circular coordinates and your linear profile.. the two would intersect here.

```
def intersect(array1, array2):
    # stuff
    return computed_array
```

Comment: What is the center for the circ_coords?

Comment: In this case its just (0,0): the circ_coords is already a function I created to create an array of values from a defined centre

Comment: You want to do it only in numpy? Because shapely has some cool functions http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html

Comment: @pseudoAJ I don't have to do it strictly in numpy no, but ill take a look at that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) has some cool functions. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844482/what-is-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-intersection-of-a-line-and-a-circle-in-py), this code should work:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point

p = Point(0,0)//center
c = p.buffer(0.71).boundary//radius
l = LineString([(0.,0.), (1., 1.)])//line point
i = c.intersection(l)
```

Apparently here i is the array you are looking for, also, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm) too. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this answer is perfect and exactly what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it algebraically. The parametric representation of points (x,y) on the line segment between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is:

x=tx1+(1−t)x2 and y=ty1+(1−t)y2,

where 0≤t≤1.

If you substitute it in the equation of the circle and solve the resulting quadratic equation for t, you can test if 0≤t01≤1, i.e line segment intersets with circle. The t01 values could be than used to calculate intersection points.