# I need to create a variable(velocity) with magnitude and direction. How can this be done?

Tags: python, vector, position, direction

Then with this velocity and acceleration and initial position find the next position(2D). The only tricky part is the creation of the vector!

Comment: Neat challenge! If you have any actual questions for us, let us know.

Comment: [Good geometry library in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076778/good-geometry-library-in-python)

Comment: I am just learning. It would have been neater if you could help me. But thanks!

Comment: Help you with what? Your only question regarding the program you intend to make was "how do I make it?".

Comment: See the vector object in vpython: http://vpython.org/contents/docs/vector.html.

Answer (score 1):

Just use standard vector math. Distance is the Pythagorean theorem and magnitude is trigonometry:

```
from math import *

class Vector2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    def direction(self):
        return degrees(atan(self.y / self.x))

    def magnitude(self):
        return sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class , then each instance (object) of that class would be a `velocity` object (vector) . A very simple example is -

```
class Velocity:
    def __init__(self, mag, direction):
        self.mag = mag
        self.direction = direction
```

Then you can create velocity objects like -

```
v1 = Velocity(5,5)
v2 = Velocity(10,15)
```

You can access the magnitude and direction of each velocity as -

```
print(v1.mag)
>> 5
print(v1.direction)
>> 5
```

The above is a minimalistic example , you will need to add whatever operations (read functions) you want our velocity object to support.

Comment: Why would direction be a `float`/`double`? it should have at least two dimensions `(i,j)`

Comment: @CoryKramer why not? In 2D `(magnitude, direction)` are perfectly fine to define a vector. They contain exactly the same information as an `(x, y)` vector would.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `velocity` tuple, where magnitude is at index 0 and direction is at index 1. Then define acceleration as a float and a `startingPos` where x is at index 0 and y is at index 1.

```
#0: magnitude 1: direction (degrees above x axis)
velocity = (2.3, 55)
acceleration = 3.2
#0: x 1: y
startingPos = (-10, 0)
```