# Geometry module for Python

Tags: python-3.x, plot, geometry, drawing

I am looking for a geometry module with similar feature as Geogebra for Python.
I would like to, from a set of defined length calculates coordinates of points and some transformations such as rotation of x degrees, symmetrical from a point from some line, compute the intersection between a circle and whatever point, compute the perpendicular line to a segment, middle point etc. Then plot a polygon obtained by joining transformed points using let's say matplotlib.

Does such a module exist ? I could build it from scratch but having those features would save me much time.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good geometry library in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076778/good-geometry-library-in-python)

Comment: Requests for software recommendations are off topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sympy](http://www.sympy.org) for some of these, in particular the [geometry module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/index.html).
[Shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) is also pretty popular.